# How to get values with addons = the value without the addons in excel.

Tags: excel, vba, formula

So below I have illustrated what I am looking to achieve in the end. I am wondering if it is possible to have the variation items *(i.e. items with -LA or -LED)* of the original item numbers *(i.e. 1114 or bb2569/10)* equal the same quantity in column B. The ending quantity should be based off of the original quantity from the original item number, *i.e. 1114 or bb2569/10*. This is only a small percentage of a much larger table of items and quantities.

```
This is what the code looks like now:       
    Item number     Quantity        
    1114               5        
    1114-LA            0        
    1114-LED           0        
    225896             20       
    129239             17       
    225896-LA          0        
    225896-LED         0        
    114895             91       
    114895-LED         0        
    114895-LA          0        
    bb2569/10          42       
    bb2569/10-LA       0        
    bb2569/10 -LED     0        
    A22596             0        
    T-22265587         7                
 here is what i need it to look like in the end:        
    Item number     Quantity        
    1114               5        
    1114-LA            5        
    1114-LED           5        
    225896             20       
    225896-LA          20       
    225896-LED         20       
    114895             91       
    114895-LED         91       
    114895-LA          91       
    bb2569/10          91       
    bb2569/10-LA       42       
    bb2569/10 -LED     42       
    A22596             0        
    T-22265587         7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in C2 and Drag/Copy Down:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,TRIM(LEFT(A2,IFERROR(FIND("-L",A2)-1,LEN(A2)))),B:B)
```

[image]